ABP Framework Deployment on IIS Authorize returns "Error?httpStatusCode=400"
We developed a web application using ABP Framework. We published the application we developed under a single domain with api and authserver applications. We also updated the application address information in the database. However, when I try to Authorize via api swagger, it gives 400 Error.

Auth Server Error Page

I made the necessary configurations on IIS, I made the domain definitions properly, I updated the Appsettings files as they should be. I am waiting for ApiServer and AuthServer to communicate properly.
